# Removing tab space from a column in R

Tags: r

Can you please help me to remove a space from the ID column in my data?
I have data frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(
  "ID" = c("G 249485", "L 938495", "N 234987"), type=c("a","b","c"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(ID = stringr::str_remove(ID, pattern = "\\s"))

       ID type
1 G249485    a
2 L938495    b
3 N234987    c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
df$ID <- str_replace(df$ID, " ", "")
df
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(ID = gsub(" ","",ID))
```